# Using dispatch outside react

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron

So I've got an Electron app that I've got react/redux wired up, and it's working great.  However, there are some filesystem things I'm doing in a regular JS class(ES6).

How can I get access to my store and dispatch actions so that my react components will pick up the changes?

Comment: can you provide some code so show us what you have so far? Maybe use the `react-redux` package?

Answer (score 0):

dispatch is just a method on your store object. So all you really need to do is initialize your store and pass store.dispatch to your class.

Depending on the order of initialization you require (if there is a required order), you would either pass dispatch in the constructor of the class or use a setter. In the latter case, you might even need to queue actions and dispatch them once the store is initialized.